# React / Redux displaying different headlines on different pages

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I just started learning React.js and now I am planning to dive a little bit deeper into Redux. My first task to get a better understanding is how to display different headlines on different pages based on click in the navigation. The action occurs in the navigation component of my app. The headline shoud be displayed in the headline/intro component. I managed to set up everything however now I am receiving the following error: **Uncaught TypeError: dispatch is not a function(…)** I think the error must be somewhere in my Navigation Component or in my Action. Thanks for your help!

**intro.js**

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react'
 import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux'
 import {connect} from 'react-redux'
 import {loadIntro} from '../actions/index'
 require('../../scss/Intro.scss');

class Intro extends Component {

render() {


        return (
            <div className="introWrapper">
                <ul>
                <h2>{this.props.activeTitle}</h2>
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }


};


function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        //The different titles
        activeTitle: state.activeTitle
    };
}
```

**Nav.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router';
import TestComponent from '../containers/test-component';
import {loadTravel} from '../actions/index'
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
require('../../scss/nav.scss');

class Nav extends Component {

 render () {
    return (
    <div>

     <nav className="wrapperNavigation">

        <ul>
            <li onClick={() => this.props.loadTravel()}><Link to="/travel" activeClassName="active">Travel</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/living" activeClassName="active">Living</Link></li>

        </ul>
     </nav> 
     </div>
    )
  }

}



function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({ loadTravel:loadTravel}, dispatch);

  }

export default connect(mapDispatchToProps)(Nav);
```

**reducer-active-intro.js**

```
export default function (state = [], action) {
        if (action.type ==="LOAD_TRAVEL") {

            var newState = Object.assign({}, state, {title:action.title});
            return newState;
            }


return state;
}
```

**actions/index.js**

```
export const loadTravel = () => {


    return {

        type: "LOAD_TRAVEL",
        title: "Schubiduu"
    }
};
```

**reducers/index.js**

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import titleReducer from './reducer-active-intro.js';
/*


const allReducers = combineReducers({
    activeTitle: titleReducer
});

export default allReducers
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mapDispatchToProps` should be the second argument to connect.

If you don't have any state mapping to be done, you can pass null as the first argument:

```
export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Nav);
```

Comment: thanks that solved my problem and I can access the state now. However I am reciving a different error now. I think its related to my object.assign in my reducer-active-intro.js.invariant.js? **Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {title}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check the render method of `Intro`.(…)**

Comment: You can ask a new question for this, although I think the error is because you are trying to modify the state object which doesn't exist

Comment: Could you accpet this as an answer

Comment: I fixed it with your help. I just got rid of the object.assign and just declared a new variable.